# Connection between $p$-adic analytic groups and linear groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I trying to prove that

> a group $G$ is $p$-adic analytic if and only if is linear (as a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb{Q}_p)$).

I'm not sure if the result is valid or if is necessary some additional hypothesis. If anyone knows some reference for a proof or a counterexample it would be a great help.

Comment: According to this page, in the second “Example,” it says this is true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-p_group?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @ThomasAndrews there is a distinction between pro-$p$ groups of this wikipedia article and $p$-adic analytic groups (which are locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $p$-adic metaplectic group gives a counterexample; see here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group

Comment: According to this page, in the second bullet in “Examples,” it says it is true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-p_group?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the wikipedia page is about pro-$p$ groups, not $p$-adic analytic groups. so e.g. $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not a pro-$p$ group